# socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js

Только начал изучать сокеты на nodejs и сразу появилась ошибка. В консоли идет ошибка socket.io net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Такое ощущение, что клиент при подключении не видит socket.io и от этого все проблемы.

Структура файлов
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "html",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
// Зависимости
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

app.set('port', 80);
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Маршруты
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

// Запуск сервера
server.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('Запускаю сервер на порте 80');
});

// Обработчик веб-сокетов
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
});

setInterval(function() {
    io.sockets.emit('message', 'hi!');
}, 1000);
```

index.html

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          canvas {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 5px solid black;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </body>
      <script>
      var socket = io();
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
    </script>
    </html>
```

После подключения к серверу - index.js падает с ошибкой

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js:270
                stream_1.pipeline(readStream, zlib_1.createGzip(), res, onError);
                         ^

TypeError: stream_1.pipeline is not a function
    at Function.sendFile (/var/www/html/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js:270:26)
    at Server.serve (/var/www/html/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js:246:16)
    at Server.srv.on (/var/www/html/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js:207:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:619:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:23)
```

Comment: ваш код работает на nodejs версии 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена - был включен фаервол, с блокировкой всех соединений кроме порта 80. Отключение фаервола позволило клиенту увидеть socket.io - соответственно все заработало.